# Detect if an image is loaded in a page outside my domain

Tags: php, image

I would like to create a single URL that returns one image when loaded in a page *within* my domain, and another slightly modified image when loaded in a page *outside* my domain.

I am thinking along the lines of something like:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: image/jpg');
    if (/**image is loaded within my domain**/)
    {
        readfile("image1.jpg");
    }
    else
    {
        readfile("image2.jpg");
    }
?>
```

Is there something I can put in the if-statement to make it work? Possibly that works in all browsers?

Is there a way to do this without php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the referrer URL in the request and check to see if it is your domain. This is done using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`.

However, the HTTP_REFERER URL can be easily modified by clients and can even sometimes not be set, so you need to be careful when using it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, how you're going to get request for image not in your domain, but you may look at `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`. Maybe, `HTTP_REFERER` is what you need. Anyway look [here](http://en.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).